# How to specify number of axis labels

Tags: r, loops, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have a df that looks like this but with 14000+ rows and 30 unique 'Vessel.Pln' identifiers;

I'm using the df to create a stacked barplot of landings by size.code by month for each vessel for a period of 10 years. I want to reduce the number of x axis labels to say every 3 months so that they are legible. I have found a few examples of ways to do it but I'm not sure how to set up an axis sequence when calling the barplot from a matrix of the df.

[image: example of axis label overcrowding]

```
    Size.Code   Date    Vessel.Pln  Weight
            2   2011-01-01  BF206   0.174330
            3   2011-01-01  BF206   0.095940
            4   2011-01-01  BF206   0.143910
            5   2011-01-01  BF206   0.407745
            2   2011-02-01  BF206   0.061425
            3   2011-02-01  BF206   0.234000
            5   2011-02-01  BF206   0.327600
            2   2011-05-01  BF206   0.081900
            3   2011-05-01  BF206   0.152100
            4   2011-05-01  BF206   0.444600
            5   2011-05-01  BF206   1.070550
            2   2011-06-01  BF206   0.273780
            3   2011-06-01  BF206   1.965600
            4   2011-06-01  BF206   0.795600
            1   2011-08-01  BF206   0.421200
            2   2011-08-01  BF206   1.329120
            3   2011-08-01  BF206   2.398500
            4   2011-08-01  BF206   2.000700
            5   2011-08-01  BF206   0.649350
            3   2011-10-01  BF206   0.056160

for (a in unique(grade$Vessel.Pln)) {
  df <- grade[grade$Vessel.Pln == a,]
  library(reshape2)
  df2 <- dcast(df,Size.Code~Date,sum)
  library(RColorBrewer)

  barplot(as.matrix(df2),main=a,
    xlim=c(0, ncol(df2) + 20),
    col=brewer.pal(nrow(df2), "Spectral"),
    ylab="Landings (tonnes)",xlab="Month",las=2,cex.names=0.4,
    args.legend=list(
    x=ncol(df2) + 3,
    y=max(colSums(df2)),
    bty = "n"
 )
)
legend(55, 
       legend = c("1", "2","3","4","5"), 
       fill =brewer.pal(nrow(df2), "Spectral"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain using base R's `barplot`, consider passing *axisnames = FALSE* and re-write with `axis()`. Below rewrites for each quarter between first and last date column.

Also, consider using `by`, the function that splits a dataframe into one or more factor(s), to run plots for each distinct *Vessel.Pln* which avoids the subset call and `for` loop. Also, be sure to remove the first column of *df2* matrix to not plot *Size.Code*:

```
by(grade, grade$Vessel.Pln, function(df) {

  df2 <- dcast(df, Size.Code ~ Date,sum, value.var="Weight")

  bp <- barplot(as.matrix(df2[-1]), axisnames = FALSE,
                main = a,
                xlim = c(0, ncol(df2) + 20),
                col = brewer.pal(nrow(df2), "Spectral"),
                ylab = "Landings (tonnes)",xlab="Month",las=2,cex.names=0.4,
                args.legend = list(
                  x = ncol(df2) + 3,
                  y = max(colSums(df2)),
                  bty = "n"
                )
  )

  legend(55, 
         legend = c("1", "2","3","4","5"), 
         fill =brewer.pal(nrow(df2), "Spectral"))

  # REWRITES AXIS FOR YEAR QUARTERS
  axis(1, at = bp[seq(1,ncol(df2[-1]), 3)], 
       labels = names(df2[-1])[seq(1, ncol(df2[-1]), 3)]
  ) 

})
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: thank you for the by function code improvement. The rewriting axis part of this is not working as expected, I failed to mention that there isn't actually data for every month for each Vessel.Pln, some have gaps of a few months. So I'm looking to label every 3rd bar with labels whatever they may be rather than give them quarterly labels.

Comment: See update where bars are now counted every third and not by quarters: 1, 4, 7, etc..